# Android - Adding views to an array using a for loops

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have the following Button views

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
```

And this Button[]:

```
Button[] buttonViewsArray = new Button[8];
```

I would like to use a for loop to add the buttons into the array, but not sure how to use the `i` variable to then reference the correct button:

```
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < buttonViewsArray.length; i++){
  String j = "button" + i;
  Button[i] = findViewById(j);
  }
```

I thought maybe create a `String` which references the correct viewID?

Comment: Internet , you can find bunch of similar or the same example,question

Comment: You can do it in one line code if you don't wana use for loop or simply use ArrayList of Buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get a resource in a loop.  Here is an example from a Sudoku app I put together (the TextViews have names of the form "tv32"):

```
// get the text views using dynamic layout IDs
for( int row=0; row<9; row++ )
   for( int col=0; col<9; col++ )
   {
       int layoutID = getResources().getIdentifier("tv"+row+col, "id", getPackageName());
       tv[row][col] = (TextView) findViewById(layoutID);
       // set text for testing
       //tv[row][col].setText(""+row+col);
       // set up to respond to click
       tv[row][col].setOnClickListener( new CellOnClickListener(row, col) );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the `R.id.button6` is an integer in the R file.

You will have to call findViewById for each button and save them in an array if you want.